# Oracle SQL missing smth

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, create-table, check-constraints

Trying to build these tables and there's always an error or missing something, can someone help me?
Where's max_mice i'm checking if it's inbetween those values and doesn't work why?
Don't know what's wrong, already searched everywhere, don't know why they won't be created...
updated: now i got problems on table incidents...

update: the error was that i had: CONSTRAINT fun_maxmi_ch CHECK (200 > max_mice >= min_mice) instead of the code below.

```
CREATE TABLE Functions (
    function VARCHAR(10) CONSTRAINT fun_fu_pk PRIMARY KEY,
    min_mice NUMBER(3) CONSTRAINT fun_minmi_ch CHECK (min_mice > 5),
    max_mice NUMBER(3),
    CONSTRAINT fun_maxmi_ch CHECK (max_mice >= min_mice and max_mice < 200)
);
```

BUT still have a problem creating table Incidents don't know what's the problem!!!

```
CREATE TABLE Incidents (
    nickname VARCHAR2(15), 
    enemy_name VARCHAR2(15), 
    incident_date DATE CONSTRAINT inc_indate_nn NOT NULL,
    incident_desc VARCHAR2(50),
    CONSTRAINT inc_con_pk PRIMARY KEY (nickname, enemy_name),
    CONSTRAINT inc_nic_fk FOREIGN KEY (nickname) REFERENCES Cats(nickname),
    CONSTRAINT inc_enname_fk FOREIGN KEY (enemy_name) REFERENCES Enemies(enemy_name),
);
```

Here's the full code:

```
CREATE TABLE Enemies (
    enemy_name VARCHAR2(15), 
    hostility_degree NUMBER(2) CONSTRAINT hos_degree_ch CHECK (hostility_degree BETWEEN 1 AND 10),
    species VARCHAR2(15),
    bride VARCHAR2(20),
    CONSTRAINT ene_name_pk PRIMARY KEY(enemy_name)
);

CREATE TABLE Functions (
    function VARCHAR(10) CONSTRAINT fun_fu_pk PRIMARY KEY,
    min_mice NUMBER(3) CONSTRAINT fun_minmi_ch CHECK (min_mice > 5),
    max_mice NUMBER(3),
    CONSTRAINT fun_maxmi_ch CHECK (max_mice >= min_mice and max_mice < 200)
); 

CREATE TABLE Bands (
    Band_no NUMBER(2) CONSTRAINT ban_no_pk PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR2(20) CONSTRAINT ban_name_nn NOT NULL,
    site VARCHAR2(15) CONSTRAINT ban_site_un UNIQUE,
    band_chief VARCHAR(15) CONSTRAINT ban_chief_un UNIQUE
);


CREATE TABLE Cats (
    name VARCHAR2(15) CONSTRAINT cat_name_nn NOT NULL,
    gender VARCHAR2(1) CONSTRAINT cat_gen_ch CHECK (gender IN('M', 'W')),
    nickname VARCHAR2(15) CONSTRAINT cat_pk PRIMARY KEY,
    function VARCHAR2(10), 
    chief VARCHAR2(15), 
    in_herd_since DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE CONSTRAINT cat_inherd_nn NOT NULL,
    mice_ration NUMBER(3),
    mice_extra NUMBER(3),
    band_no NUMBER(2),
    CONSTRAINT cat_banno_fk FOREIGN KEY (band_no) REFERENCES Bands(band_no),
    CONSTRAINT cat_chief_fk FOREIGN KEY (chief) REFERENCES Cats(nickname),
    CONSTRAINT cat_fun_fk FOREIGN KEY (function) REFERENCES Functions(function)
);

ALTER TABLE Bands 
ADD CONSTRAINT ban_chief_fk FOREIGN KEY (band_chief) REFERENCES Cats(nickname);


CREATE TABLE Incidents (
    nickname VARCHAR2(15), 
    enemy_name VARCHAR2(15), 
    incident_date DATE CONSTRAINT inc_indate_nn NOT NULL,
    incident_desc VARCHAR2(50),
    CONSTRAINT inc_con_pk PRIMARY KEY (nickname, enemy_name),
    CONSTRAINT inc_nic_fk FOREIGN KEY (nickname) REFERENCES Cats(nickname),
    CONSTRAINT inc_enname_fk FOREIGN KEY (enemy_name) REFERENCES Enemies(enemy_name),
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> here's max_mice i'm checking if it's in between those values and doesn't work why?

When it comes to the first table in your code, `Functions`, the problem is with the declaration of the last check constraint:

```sql
    max_mice NUMBER(3) CONSTRAINT fu_maxmi_ch CHECK (200 > max_mice >= min_mouse)
```

Issues:

- the double inequality condition is not supported
- a multi-column check constraint need to be declared at table level rather than at column level

This works:

```
CREATE TABLE Functions (
    function VARCHAR(10) CONSTRAINT fu_fu_pk PRIMARY KEY,
    min_mice NUMBER(3) CONSTRAINT fu_minmi_ch CHECK (min_mice > 5),
    max_mice NUMBER(3),
    CONSTRAINT fu_maxmi_ch CHECK (max_mice >= min_mice and max_mice < 200)
);
```

Note: I would not recommend naming a column `function`, since it obviously conflicts with a SQL keyword.